# Where are App Store certificates and provisioning profiles stored in my Mac book?

Tags: macos, app-store

I am planning to give my mac book to my friend for some time.

Where are app store certificates and provisioning profiles stored so that I can remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Certificates are usually kept in your Keychain, but make sure you didn't export a copy somewhere by searching for .cer and .p12 files.  Provisioning profiles are usually stored in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ , but are fairly useless without the matching certificates.